# Creating a 4 Directional Scroll View

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I want to create a scroll view that can scroll up, down, left and right. Im wondering if i should extend ScrollView and then just modify the onDraw() method or if it would just be easier to just do it all from scratch. I could do it from scratch pretty easily but it would take a long time, would it be faster to extends ScrollView or HorizontalScrollView and then try to modify it from there? I dont want to put a ScrollView inside of a HorizontalScrollView because then the application tends to act clunky and it doesnt scroll both directions at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test it but it should be as easy as this. Sometimes the easiest answer is the best one :) ... sometimes

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent">




    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: This leads to "clunky" behavior, only one ScrollView can scroll at one time, which means that you cant scroll horizontally and vertically at the same time.

Comment: Ok, you're right, just one View can be focused at the same time. Maybe a look at the WebView would help and build your own view from scratch. That's what I would do.